# White screen across whole of site including wp-admin

Tags: errors

On a MacBook I have downloaded a WP multisite over SFTP using FileZilla. I have also exported copies of all the required databases. I have updated all `wp-config` files to match my local DB settings.

The problem I’m having is that I get a white screen on both front and back end. I can’t even see the login screen at `wp-login.php`

I’ve tried the following with no luck:

- matched my local PHP version to the live server version
- set `WP_DEBUG` to true
- added `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to `wp-config`
- added `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` to `wp-config`
- increased `memory_limit` from 128 to 512
- set `WP_CACHE` to false

There is nothing in `debug-log` or my local error log and there are no errors showing on the screen.

As I cannot access wp-admin, I have also tried the following with no luck:

- renamed the plugins folder
- removed the theme being used from the themes folder

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you tell us what errors are logged after you have activated WP_DEBUG_LOG ?

Comment: Apologies, just edited my question

Comment: Ih you are having a white screen on the website, have you tried to created a simple ``index.html`` at the root of your local server just to test if you manage to see it? If you still get a white screen then it might not be your WordPress the problem but a missconfiguration of your local server.

Comment: The test index.html is working fine, never experienced anything like this before

Comment: Have you check the *server* logs? (Not the `debug.log` or `error_log` file) How about temporarily rename the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Hi, I’ve already got rid of the .htaccess files and the server log is showing nothing either. I’ve been doing some extensive searching on this and wondering whether there might be some white space before one of the opening `<?php` tags?

Comment: It could happen, although things like that should make PHP put the error in the logs. But you should just check the files for any unwanted characters which the OS may have added during the download.. Have you tried re-generating the [security keys](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)?

Comment: No, I’ve not tried regenerating the security keys yet, so thanks for that. I will try that first in the morning before going through the files. I’ll update here if I find the solution. Thanks all for your input

Comment: Based on what Sally CJ wrote, you could just try a fresh WordPress installation in an other folder to test if your environment can run this new WordPress.  If it does, then the problem might comes from your download.

Answer (score 1):

Just coming back to this. Unfortunately, the client had provided us with an incorrect copy of the site and whilst all the necessary files were in place and looked OK, this was the cause of the issue.